# Ignore @Value field processing of dependent libraries from Spring Bean Post Processor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am using one of our projects as a dependency in another. One of the classes in the dependent project is as follows:

```
@Service
public class Dependency {

  @Value("${xyz.value}")
  private String xyz;

  @Value("${abc.value}")
  private String abc;

  public Dependency() {

  }

  public Dependency(String xyz, String abc) {
    this.xyz = xyz;
    this.abc = abc;
  }
}
```

I am trying to create an instance of `Dependency` in another project on startup as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {
    "classpath:appEnv.properties"
}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)

public class Test {

  @Bean(name = "dependencyBean")
  public Dependent getDependent() {
    return new Dependent("xyz", "abc");
  }
}
```

Trying to access the `dependencyBean` created as follows

```
public class SomeClass {

  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
  Dependent d = ctx.getBean("dependencyBean"); 

}
```

I am getting the following exception

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependentBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String xyz;

How can I create an instance of Dependent class without invoking `postProcessPropertyValues` which tries to resolve the fields with `@Value` annotation?

Comment: Why do you want to create `Dependency` is already a bean(even though its in another project), Just autowire it and use it in your project

Comment: Not very clear with what you're trying to do.

Comment: When I try to autowire, it get a compile time exception `No beans of 'Dependent' type found`

Comment: try my answer @Conquest

Comment: @Deadpool I tried your solution but its creating `Dependent` objects with null values.. @Antariksh I am trying to create an object of `Dependent` type using `new`. When I try to use that bean from the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` using `annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBean` it is trying to resolve `@Value` annotations on the class and failing. But I am trying to get the bean that is created using `new`.

Comment: why not set some default properties in your `application.yml` for those properties? @Conquest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, first, need to enable bean overriding with;

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

and just have your custom bean have the exact name as the `@Service` annotated class;

```
@Bean(name = "dependency")
public Dependency getDependent() {
    return new Dependency("xyz", "abc");
}
```

Thus you can override the `@Service` annotated `Dependency` with your manually initialized bean. But to achieve that, you first have to disallow your custom `getDependent()` resulting bean to trigger `@Value` annotations, to do that, you need to change your `Dependency` class `@Value` injection method to constructor. When it is like that, only when Spring automatically injects, the `@Value` annotations will trigger, when you manually call `new Dependency("xyz", "abc")`, they won't.

```
@Service
public class Dependency {

    private String xyz;
    private String abc;

    @Autowired
    public Dependency(@Value("${xyz.value}") String xyz, @Value("${abc.value}") String abc) {
        this.xyz = xyz;
        this.abc = abc;
    }
}
```

With these changes, you'll have no error with your custom bean autowired.